# Regex for only allowing 2 or 3 occurences of 2 characters A and H

Tags: regex

With my minimal regex experience I am struggling to come up with a regex that incorporates both rules.

Language: Scala

Rules:

1. A and H must not occur in sequences of 3 in a row e.g. AHHHA is not valid
2. In a sequence of 5, there must be 2 A's and 3 H's OR 3 H's and 2 A's

Valid: `AHAHAHAHHAHAAHHAAHHAAHAHHAHAHAHAHAHAHA`

Invalid Rule 1: `AHAHAHAHHAHAAHHAAHHAAHAHHAHAHAHAHAHHHA`

Valid Rule 1, Invalid Rule 2: `HHAHHAAHHAHAAHHAAHHAAHAHHAHAHAHAHAHHAH`

https://regex101.com/r/pyODql/3 This satisfies rule 1 but I am unsure how to satisfy rule 2.

Any help or advice appreciated.

Comment: What language are you trying to do this in? It might be easier to make use of some of the in-built functions, rather than use a regex specifically.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that, using Scala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic idea is making use of negative lookahead, to make sure certain pattern does not appear in the string.

For rule 1, we have `A{3}` and `H{3}` which is straight-forward, that you do not want 3 consecutive A/H to appear.

For rule 2, the only cases that does not violate Rule 1 are `AAHAA` and `HHAHH`

Combining all these, you have

```
^(?!.*(A{3}|H{3}|AAHAA|HHAHH))[AH]*$
```

Explanation

```
^                                     start of string
 (?!                         )        negative-look-ahead group, i.e. not followed by
    .*                                any occurrence of any char
      (A{3}|H{3}|AAHAA|HHAHH)         followed by the 4 cases I described above
                               [AH]*  (actual matching of the string) any occurrence of A/H
                                    $  end of string
```

Answer (score 0):

Use negative a look ahead for 3 same:

```
^(?!.*(AAA|HHH|AAHAA|HHAHH))[AH]*$
```

"Rule 2" also needed 2 special cases `AAHAA|HHAHH` added to the look ahead.

Comment: Wrong for your argument on Rule 2.  A counter-example is "AAHAA", for which there is no 3 consecutive values, yet still failing rule 2

Comment: @Adrian quite so (I’ve added those exceptions to my negative look ahead).

Answer (score 0):

While the first rule will eliminate most problematic combinations for rule 2, it would not prevent instances when the outer characters are paired such as `AAHAA` and `HHAHH`. As such, the second rule must be taken into consideration.

The easiest way to exclude these paired outer characters would be to specify them explicitly in the negative lookahead:

```
/(?!.*(A{3}|H{3}|AAHAA|HHAHH))[AH]{5}/
```

Which can be seen in the following:

```js
var regex = /(?!.*(A{3}|H{3}|AAHAA|HHAHH))[AH]{5}/;

console.log("Should be valid:");
console.log("AAHHA:", regex.test('AAHHA'));
console.log("AHHAA:", regex.test('AHHAA'));
console.log("AHAHA:", regex.test('AHAHA'));
console.log("HAHAH:", regex.test('HAHAH'));

console.log('');

console.log("Should be invalid due to rule 1:");
console.log("AAAAA:", regex.test('AAAAA'));
console.log("AAAAH:", regex.test('AAAAH'));
console.log("AAAHH:", regex.test('AAAHH'));
console.log("AAHHH:", regex.test('AAHHH'));
console.log("AHHHH:", regex.test('AHHHH'));
console.log("HHHHH:", regex.test('HHHHH'));

console.log('');

console.log("Should be invalid due to rule 2:");
console.log("AAHAA:", regex.test('AAHAA'));
console.log("HHAHH:", regex.test('HHAHH'));
```

And also on **[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/shZmJl/1)** (with a few other tests).

Comment: Instead of `[AH]{5}`, I think it should be `[AH]*` or at least `[AH]{5,}` instead?

Comment: I've gone with the theory that the text is 'grouped' into sets of 5. I'm not sure whether groups are allowed to overlap or not, but that would certainly be a good way to cover it if they are :)

Comment: I don't think OP asked for "group in 5".  If it is his intention, his "Invalid Rule 1" sample won't fail, coz that 3 consecutive `H`s are splitted into two groups

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a lookahead you could use an alternation to check if your string contains one of the invalid matches and if it does the string is not valid.

It first checks for the triple variant. For a combination of 5 you are left
with `AAHAA` or `HHAHH` because the other invalid combinations will be matched by the first rule matching the triple variant.

[`(?:AAA|HHH|AAHAA|HHAHH)`](https://regex101.com/r/esnyxQ/1)

```
val pattern = "(?:AAA|HHH|AAHAA|HHAHH)".r
val s = "AHAHAHAHHAHAAHHAAHHAAHAHHAHAHAHAHAHAHA"

pattern.findFirstIn(s) match {
  case None => println(s"OK for: $s")
  case _ => println(s"Not OK for: $s")
}
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/IAIEXR67763)